# How target locking woks?

Tags: aircraft

In many aerial war face movies they show that aircraft is locked by missile ,particularly in movie ***behind enemy line*** " F/A-18 Hornet" is locked by 2 ***SAM missile***,pliot try to break the lock but aircraft get shot down. 
i find wikipedia have some  [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_lock-on) about this.
i dont understand this concept ,how this locking work and how pilot break the lock?

Comment: This is an engineering--rather than physics--question. The underling sensors may be sufficiently physics focused to be on-topic, but "lock on" is an idea that lives at the system level and has no basis in physics.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, there are a lot of things you could Google out or just wiki it. As far as I've skimmed throughout [Missile locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_guidance), there are two ways mostly used to guide missiles...

**1) Heat Seekers:** Some missiles such as the portable [Stingers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinger_missile) or some others hanged to smaller air-crafts use this kind. This method allows the missiles to passively sense the heat produced from the nozzle of aircraft and [track it along](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infra-red_search_and_track) the way to BOOM. (commonly referred to as "[IR homing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_homing)")

**2) [Radio-guided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_radar_homing):** I have a thought that these are the **less** widely used ones. They track their targets by using Radar (radio waves). They send radio signals from their oscillators (specific frequency) which hit the targets and return back to them.

The secret that EM waves are most widely used in *tracking down* targets because those have the speed $c$ which necessarily means that they could cover 300 meters in just a microsecond ($\mu s$)...

**NOTE:** There are other methods such as LASER & GPS guidance (perhaps, not used in all) and such missiles are classified to be *smart*...

Comment: Or, just have a look at [Howstuffworks](http://science.howstuffworks.com/cruise-missile.htm) for more GUI :-)